# Rails 3 AuthenticityTokens never match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

I'm having a very strange problem right now: I'm submitting a very standard form to a create action, and it always fail with ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken.
What's incredibly strange is that I *do not touch* the hidden field in the form, and when I submit I see the authenticity_token in the params, but the value inside _csrf_token is different (I don't know if it's supposed to be the same, just a wild guess).
Still, it always fails, the tokens don't match.

The form is 100% normal, no Ajax or multipart. I use warden for authentication, but it definitely shouldn't be a problem.

Someone has any idea, at least were to look ?

Here is the controller code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [ :show ]

  def new; end

  def create
    if @user = User.create( params[ :user ] )
      redirect_to dashboard_url( :subdomain => @user.subdomain )
    else
      Rails.logger.debug @user.errors.full_messages
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
  end

end
```

And here is the view:

```
<p> Is this you ? </p>

<%= form_for @user, :url => url_for( :controller => 'users', :action => 'create' )  do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :given_name, "Name" %>:
  <%= f.text_field :given_name %>

  <br />

  <%= f.label :family_name, "Surname" %>:
  <%= f.text_field :family_name %>

  <br />

  <%= f.label :location, "Location" %>:
  <%= f.text_field :location %>

  <br />

  <%= f.label :gender, "Gender" %>:
  <%= f.text_field :gender %>

  <br />

  <%= f.label :birthday, "Birthday" %>:
  <%= f.text_field :birthday %>

  <br />

  <%= f.label :email, "Email" %>:
  <%= f.text_field :email %>

  <br />

  <%= f.label :url, "URL" %>:
  <%= f.text_field :url %>

  <br />

  <%= f.label :subdomain, "subdomain" %>:
  <%= f.text_field :subdomain %>

  <br />

  <%= submit_tag "Save" %>

<% end -%>
```

This is the backtrace with the 2 requests:

```
Started GET "/facebook/callback?code=de9cba64ae1a3d1e667a6ad0-563636354%7CFKnAiPEMDocIONSUgkU7L1zDIj0" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Nov 12 22:06:15 -0800 2010
  Processing by SessionsController#facebook_callback as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"de9cba64ae1a3d1e667a6ad0-563636354|FKnAiPEMDocIONSUgkU7L1zDIj0"}
style_jam_development['users'].find({:email=>"ngw@nofeed.org"}, {}).limit(-1)
Rendered sessions/facebook_callback.html.erb within layouts/application (8.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1991ms (Views: 17.5ms)


Started POST "/users/create" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Nov 12 22:06:19 -0800 2010
  Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Save", "authenticity_token"=>"qW67SXW12n6UZj1ApJi5oy9IqWB6n8BxXmgS70s2VOA=", "utf8"=>"\342\234\223", "user"=>{"location"=>"Seattle, Washington", "url"=>"http://nofeed.org", "gender"=>"male", "subdomain"=>"", "family_name"=>"Wieland", "birthday"=>"1978-12-19", "given_name"=>"Nicholas", "email"=>"ngw@nofeed.org"}}
Completed   in 0ms

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):


Rendered /Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.8ms)
Rendered /Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (259.4ms)
Rendered /Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (284.8ms)
```

Comment: Can you carefully watch your log and make sure the form isn't submitted twice? If it is, we'll need to see your controller code. Also, as crazy as it may be, some browser extension could be doing this.

Comment: Agreed, either posted twice or perhaps something is fetching the form again (an image with no src?) and that's causing a new token to get saved in the session.

Comment: I might have found the reason of this mess. Will verify and answer myself.